# Passing Object through intent, object can't be serializable

Tags: java, android, android-intent, serializable

I have looked throughout Google and Stack Overflow and found that this should work when trying to pass an object through an Intent.

[image]

However I still get this error: 
[image]

This doesn't make sense as multiple websites have said this should work. Also here is where I try to retrieve it:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post code as text, not images. Apparently, `Horse` is neither `Parcelable` nor `Serializable`. You might consider editing your question and posting the source code to `Horse` (again, as text, please).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast your class to **Serializable**, you need to implement it in your class like this:

```
 class Horse implements Serializable{
    //Your code here
}
```